# Is the emitter-base diode forward biased when an NPN transistor is used as an amplifier?

Tags: bjt, npn

I came across a question asking about the state of both the emitter-base \$EB\$ and collector-base \$CB\$ diodes when an NPN transistor is used in amplification.

My understanding is that for amplification to happen, the \$EB\$ diode must be forward biased and the \$CB\$ must be reverse biased to cause the desired amplification, butI saw the question [online](https://testbook.com/question-answer/when-the-transistor-is-used-as-an-amplifier--5eff0126c609580d0d85445c#:%7E:text=So%2C%20Transistor%20to%20be%20used,junction%20must%20be%20forward%20biased.) on two separate platforms,  with the complete opposite answer: the \$EB\$ is reverse biased and the \$CE\$ is forward biased. It got me very confused.

What is the correct configuration of diodes for the transistor to work as an amplifier, and what are the reasons behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a BJT is used as an amplifier element, the emitter-base diode is forward biased. Because we are discussing an amplifier not a switch, we will *assume* the transistor does not go into saturation. With this assumption in place, the base collector junction is reverse biased. (Note, however, that not all BJT amplifiers avoid transistor saturation.)

Contrary to a comment, it makes no difference whether you call the diode consisting of emitter and base the emitter-base diode or base-emitter diode. Forward bias means the p-doped region is more positive than the n-doped region. How you refer to the diode doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the emitter junction is in the conductive, forward biased state, while the collector junction is reverse biased, only conducting because of injection from the emitter. But, of course, the transistor doesn't care what words I use. The best way to understand this stuff is to build some circuits, try them out.

Answer (score 2):

**Common Sense Answer**

Assuming the **by far** most common amplification region ("forward active") and "forward bias" meaning the junction diode is conducting and "reverse bias" meaning the junction diode is non-conducting: Your understanding is correct and the answer provided in your link is wrong.

**Pedantic Answer**

There are several things to unpack here. First of all what does the author in the link mean by "forward/reverse biased junction"? I agree with you when using that terminology in the context of BJTs, it's about the diode (see common sense answer).

However, "Emitter-base junction reverse biased" could simply mean the E junction is at lower potential than the B junction, completely disregarding the conduction state of the diode (in a NPN type the BE diode would be conducting, in a PNP type it wouldn't).

Then there is a rarely used amplification region called "reverse active" where the junction diodes have the opposite bias compared to the far more common "forward active" region.

So the answer given in your link would be correct in the following cases:

- It's about a NPN type's "forward region" and "Emitter-base junction reverse biased" actually means "Emitter at lower potential than base" and "Collector-base junction forward biased" actually means "Collector at higher potential than base".
- It's about a NPN or PNP type's "reverse active" region.

The "reverse active" case appears pretty far fetched to me. So I'm guessing the author just has a misconception about the terminology. In the detailed explanation below there even appears the term "collector-emitter junction" which doesn't make any sense whatsoever.